# Can not use Kotlin to config Spring JPA Entity with Abstract Class

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, configuration

I am trying to use Kotlin in Spring project and I found that with entities extends abstract class. Kotlin can not tell the annotation in abstract class. The configuration is as below.

Base.kt

```
package io.qiyue.dream.entity

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
abstract class Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    open var id: String? = null

    @Column(name = "last_modified_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    open val lastModifiedAt: LocalDateTime? = null

    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    open val lastModifiedBy: String? = null

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    @CreatedBy
    open val createdBy: String? = null

}
```

Role.kt

```
package io.qiyue.dream.entity

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "q_role")
open class Role (val name: String) : Base(){
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would also not work in Java.

You need to add @MappedSuperclass to your base class to tell JPA that it must include all properties from the base class:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Base {
```

Comment: Got that, I missed that annotation. Thanks.